# How many Amazon SQS ReceiveMessageRequest i can perform on single sqs queue using multiple consumer

Tags: queue, message, amazon-sqs

I have sqs queue "someQueue" and i have implemented multiple 100 consumer for it.
i added wait_time_seconds as 20 seconds.
now i am getting

"com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool"

Is there any limit for receive message request?
or i am missing something?

Comment: Are you getting this error continuously or intermittently?

Comment: i got this continuously as i try for connections in loop, this goes off as i restart the server, and some time after it came back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS default connection pool size is 50 connections, for one client.
when i reduced the connection request to less than 50 it worked for me.